# How to change the `temp` directory path of android `sdk`?

Tags: android, sdk

Since I reinstalled my `OS`, the path which `android sdk` points to became invalid.
So, everytime I try to download or update something from `sdk`, it fails.
I've searched many places for the solution but couldn't get a definite answer. for e.g.

```
    `C:\Users\GANESH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation40\android\repository\extras\intel\haxm-windows_r6_0_6.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

the above path is invalid, as the `username` has changed since then. How to change it?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: Windows 10, sorry for the late reply though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that the question was still unanswered.
I ended up copying my entire sdk to a different folder.
& Every time I open my old projects, studio prompts me that path not found & asks me to direct it to new sdk.
That eventually, also fixed the update issues I was facing

Answer (score 4):

As I found out recently, previous temporary folder destination is located in the `.installer/.installData` file.
The file will be generated in each component. So to change the temporary folder I have had to find every folder `.install` in SDK location and remove them all.

Comment: I actually fixed it in a different way. & because that's already solved. Can't give a try to your solution. Sorry I should have posted the fix as soon as I found that.Maybe it would have helped you too. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

Met the same issue today. My Android SDK was installed in D:\Android_dev\sdk\platforms when using Windows 7 then I re-install Windows 10 and change the username. When I want to install a new platform it prints "An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 25: C:\Users\old_name
\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation01\platform-25_r03.zip". However it gets done when I install android-26 platform.

I resolve this by remove "D:\Android_dev\sdk\platforms\android-25". Some old download infomation might hides here.

Comment: how did you removed the path?

Comment: I mean remove the "D:\Android_dev\sdk\platforms\android-25" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem today. I solved it by renaming the path inside the file .installData located at "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"